# RedirectMatch and including L flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need some help to add the **LAST or L** flag together with the 301 on that RedirectMatch.

The code I'm using, which looks like below works, but only have **301** status

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(folder1|folder2)($|/.*) http://fedmich.com/$1$2
```

I've tried these variations and they don't work or have Internal server error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(folder1|folder2)($|/.*) http://fedmich.com/$1$2 #not working
RedirectMatch [R=301,L] ^/(folder1|folder2)($|/.*) http://fedmich.com/$1$2 #SERVER error
RewriteRule ^/(folder1|folder2)($|/.*) http://fedmich.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]    #No error, but not redirecting at all
```

I'm scanning **page headers** on every tests codes I make so it's not being "cached" and not redirected incorrectly.

Thanks guys

---

References

> RedirectMatch http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch
>
> FLAGS - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Do you have more rules below above rule that you don't want to execute after above rule has executed?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to optimize the htaccess and also limit the size of the file... it's getting a bit big

Answer (score 4):

You can't add rewrite flags to the `RedirectMatch` directive. The rewrite stuff is part of mod_rewrite, the redirect stuff is part of mod_alias. If you want to use 'L', you can use mod_rewrite instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2)($|/.*) http://fedmich.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

But I'm not understanding the underlying problem of *why* you'd need the `L` flag here. Are there other rules that you don't want to get applied?

Comment: Thanks Jon, seems to be right and couldnt use flags there. Yes, I need the L/LAST to break and stop other rules from running.

Comment: @fedmich `^/(folder1|folder2)($|/.*)`, you can't have a leading slash if you have rules in the htaccess file. See the pattern in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Last flag (L) in mod_rewrite doesn't stop further rules to be executed. It just acts as `continue` in a while loop and re-injects rewritten URI to `mod_rewrite` so that further rules can be executed.

If you want to skip rewrite rules for certain conditions then have a rewrite rule like this **before other rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar|baz)/ - [NC,L]
```

With this rule in place any URI that matches `/foo/` OR `/bar/` OR `/baz/` will not be impacted by any rewrite rules below this rule.